# Audi A3 2001 1.9 TDI ASV - which motor oil to use?

Tags: oil, oil-change, audi

Which oil I should use? I have no reference guide in which I could tell what kind of oil to use. I live in Slovenia where lowest temperature is around -15°C and the highest at around 40°C. The thing I am really wondering about is what viscosity level to use.

Would Castrol Edge Turbo Diesel 5W-40 be a good choice or should I go with a 5W-30?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** For anyone that's interested in which one I chose, I just went to [Castrol Oil Selector](http://applications.castrol.com/oilselector/en_gb/c/search), selected my vehicle and got **Castrol EDGE 5W-30 LL** as a result, I just went with that one as it was **5W-30** as stated on my engine, was for all engine types and supports a wide variety of standards: ACEA C3, MB-APPROVAL 229.31, MB-APPROVAL 229.51, PORSCHE C30, **VW 504 00**, **VW 507 00**, FULFILS THE REQUIREMENTS OF THE FORMER **VW 503 01** SPECIFICATION.

Comment: 2001, I mentioned it in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the 5w40 is fine for that car, but more importantly make sure the oil meets the VW 507.00 spec.  These specifications are very important for turbo diesels, so don't use just any oil.  If you have any doubts, I would just go buy some oil from the VW/Audi dealer in your area.  Paying a little more for oil is better than the alternative, but you should be able to find some properly spec'd oil at you local parts store.

I'm pretty sure the Castrol Edge fits the bill - I just wanted to point out the important part for anyone else reading this in the future.

Comment: How do you know my car uses 507.00 spec? Can I look that up somewhere online?

Comment: I'm not sure of an official place to look it up online...  There have been a few specs over the years.  505.01 was for a "standard service" and there was a 506.01 for "extended interval service".  That has been superseded by the 507.00 spec.  The dealer can certainly verify this, and it's all over TDI forums.  A lot of people think that weight is the only number to care about on oil, but TDI's are a little more particular - if you want the "right" oil and the best engine protection. But to answer "how do I know" - I have a 2.0 TDI and have researched it.